# Magento 2.3 - Products URL key regenerate on import functionality

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, products, importexport, url-key

I update the products with no `url_key` header present (only `sku`,`description`) using the import functionality

The import should only update the fields which are mentioned in the CSV file.

The import removes the URL keys from admin against every sku mentioned in the CSV and URL keys regenerate from the name against each product sku.